# Sed - not working- Nothing is updated and no error

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have the ip-address stored in a parameter called Worker1 and another ip-address is stored in SPARK_MASTER_IP

```
echo $Worker1
10.100.53.185
echo $SPARK_MASTER_IP
10.100.53.218
```

I am trying to replace the line discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [127.0.0.1] like below line.

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.100.53.218","10.100.53.185"]
```

When i try to use the below command using sed, Nothing is updated and no error. Please help me with a solution

```
sed -i -e "s/discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [127.0.0.1]/discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["'$SPARK_MASTER_IP'","'$Worker1'"]/g" /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

Thanks!

Comment: you need to escape the [] they define list of characters in the regular expression. so instead of [127.0.0.1] you should have \\[127.0.0.1\\] second did you want the value in the file to use the evironement variables you can just use ' instead of " around the whole expression. and avoid the "'$varible'" thing. Also though not likely an issue I would escape the . in the 127.0.0.1 because in regex . mean ANY character so it would match 127A0B0C01 so \\[127\.0\.0\.1\\]

Comment: Thanks ! it is not reading the ipaddress from $Worker1 $SPARK_MASTER_IP
sed -i -e "s/discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: \
 [127.0.0.1\]/discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: \[\"'$SPARK_MASTER_IP'\",\"'$Worker1'\"\]/g" /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

Comment: @Swat: Refer my answer below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed over in the comments, escaping the `[` will do the trick for you,

```
WORKER1="10.100.53.185"
SPARK_MASTER_IP="10.100.53.218"

sed -e 's/discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: \["10.100.53.218","10.100.53.185"\]/discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: \["'$WORKER1'","'$SPARK_MASTER_IP'"\]/g' file
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.100.53.185","10.100.53.218"]
```

Add the `-i` flag for the in-place replacement, once you confirm the replacement to be happening successfully.

Comment: I am trying to use sed in json and ip-address are not passed, pls help
"su - root -c 'sed -i -e \"s/discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: \\[127\\.0\\.0\\.1\\]/discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: \\[\\\"$SPARK_MASTER_IP\\\",\\\"$Worker1\\\"\\]/g\" /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml'\n",